# Multi arraylist, trying to store timestamp with data

Tags: java, arraylist

We have the code below which is a simple loop iterating through an arraylist and storing  each iterated value into another arraylist. Each time an iteration is achieved,  a timestamp value is obtained. How do we create or change the existing arrylist to store both a value and a timestamp together. Can we create a multi dimentional arraylist to do this ie arraylist [0],[0]. if so how?

```
 int counter = 0; //current number of iterations
 ArrayList<String> logData = new ArrayList<String>();

 while (counter < TemData.size()) {

     Thread.sleep(5000); // Sleep for 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
     nowTime = new GetCurrentTimeStamp(); 

     logData.add((String) TemData.get(counter));

     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Outputting Array Data >> " + logData.get(counter));

     //add to timestamp ArrayList
     nowTime = new GetCurrentTimeStamp();

     counter++; //increment counter)
}
```

This is GetCurrentTimeStamp class

```
public class GetCurrentTimeStamp {
public GetCurrentTimeStamp()
public GetCurrentTimeStamp() {
     //Date object
     Date date= new Date();
     //getTime() returns current time in milliseconds
     long time = date.getTime();
     //Passed the milliseconds to constructor of Timestamp class 
     Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
     System.out.println("Time Stamp >> "+ts);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Also, that is a pretty weird way to keep track of your TImestamp, based on what I understand from your code. You might just consider using `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of Instantiating a  `Date` or `Timestamp` at all. This would have a lower overhead, and you could always get a new `new Timstamp(long)` later on when you retrieve the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a simple class to store your values?

```
class MyData {
    private String myString;
    private Timestamp myTime;

    MyData(String string, Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.myString = string;
        this.myTime = timestamp;
    }

    // getters and setters of your choosing
}
```

Then in your code, instead of 
`ArrayList<String> logData = new ArrayList<String>();` do a `ArrayList<MyData> logData = new ArrayList<MyData>();` instead.

In your loop you could do something like

```
MyData myData = new MyData((String) TemData.get(counter), nowtime);
logData.add(myData);
```

... or tweak the actual add to the `ArrayList` based on which value of `nowTime` you wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional Arrays are possible, as are multidimensional ArrayLists, but I don't think that's what you need.

Just to reiterate what you're trying to do: You're trying to store a `String` and a `Timestamp` together.  The simplest way of doing this with arrays is somewhat crude.  You make two arrays: One for the `String`s and one for the `Timestamp`s, and you 'associate' values via their index.  Eg:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Timestamp> times= new ArrayList<Timestamp>();

...

strings.get(5); // Your sixth logged entry
times.get(5); // and its associate timestamp
```

Like I said this is crude, and prone to errors because you need to ensure the indices match up at all times.

Another possibility is to use an associative collection of some sort.  Hash maps come to mind.  For example:

```
HashMap<Timestamp, String> logEntries = new HashMap<Timestamp, String>();
logEntries.put(GetCurrentTimeStamp(), (String) TemData.get(counter));
```

When searching/iterating through the collection, you would iterate through all of the keys in `logEntries.keySet()`.  Eg:

```
for (Timestamp key : logEntries.keySet())
{
    String value = logEntries.get(key);
    // Do your processing here - you now know the key and value pair.
}
```